# Relative padding and vh units - bug or spec misunderstanding?

Tags: css, viewport-units

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/larrybotha/pen/xstDK)**

Sometimes I'll create a square (or any rectangle, really) that will respect its ratio at any size using a method similar to [this method](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html).

**What I want:**

- to prevent the square extending outside of the viewport on devices with a small height
  i.e. mobile phone in landscape

**Proposed solution**

- limit width of square to a percentage of viewport height using `max-width: 90vh`
- expect ratio to be respected

*CSS*

```
    .square {
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .square-inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

    .mw { max-width: 90vh;} /* solution, but makes things break */
```

*HTML*

```
    <div class="square mw">
        <div class="square-inner"></div>
    </div>
```

**What should happen**

- in viewports with small heights, the square should be a max width of 90% of the viewport height

**What actually happens:**

- when *viewport* height is less than width of square:

  - width is constrained as per `vh` value
  - height is calculated from width of square had it *not* been constrained to `vh`
  - we get a vertically long rectangle

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) says that the relative value is calculated from the 'containing block', which to me seems as though it should be the current width of the container.

**Browser behaviour:**

- Chrome 29.0.1547.65: as described
- Firefox 23.01: as described
- <s>Opera: does not respect vh at all</s> Not validated with Opera 16+

Am I interpreting the spec incorrectly, or is this a possible bug in implementation by browser vendors?

Comment: Please post the actual code (ideally an [SSCCEE](http://sscce.org)) in the question. Questions should not depend on external resources to be legible/answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in using both lengths in % and vh.

Try this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxRa9/4/)**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.neat {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 90vh;    /*** Important bit changed width:50%; to width:90vh; ***/
  max-width: 50%; /*** Important bit added max-width:50%; ***/
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square-inner {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.mw {
  max-width: 90vh;
}
```

Comment: this works as expected - but the repaint issue is too prevalent for me to actually use this in production. Nice solution. I've tested by placing a container outside the square so that the column is not modified (as it is part of the grid), with the container placing constraints on the width - works as expected, apart from quirks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Opera supports vh,and there are known issues. I'm wondering if this bug is affecting what you're seeing:  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124331.

Comment: haha, I see now that caniuse.com is displaying values for Opera 16 - I failed to see that: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh. There seem to be quite a few quirks with vh - my demo loads with the container collapsed, but the resize event seems to then trigger the correct paint. Repaints, as with your link, seem to resolve some of the issues.